# Save Trained PySpark ML Pipeline to local file system

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark pipeline that looks like this,

```
scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaled_features")
pca = PCA(inputCol=scaler.getOutputCol(), outputCol="pca_output")
kmeans = clustering.KMeans(seed=2014)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[scaler, pca, kmeans])
```

I trained this pipleline over my data and I can produce outputs with it.

Now, I want to save this model to disk and later use it another piece of code.

I'm able to call save method on the pipeline object and save it to hdfs like this,

```
pipeline.save("test_pipe")
```

I want to save the pipeline to local file system though for later use.

I've tried to write like this but failed with an error,

```
pipeline.save("file:///home/test_pipe")
```

How can save the trained pipeline to local file system?